# IIS rewrite rule to a different port

Tags: iis, rewrite

This simple IIS rewrite rule should send requests to another http-server application on the same machine but it does not. Any idea why?

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule">
                    <match url="/app/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:88/app/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

URLs like http://server.domain.com/something should go to IIS running on port 80. URLs like http://server.domain.com/app/something should be sent to an application running on port 88 but the log says "POST /app/something HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Should be mistake 3.

Comment: You are right. ARR is missing. Thank you!